# Jquery Animate height toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

I am using JQuery for making a widget effect i.e. minimizing and maximizing a widget..

But the problem is that when i click on the minimize button speedily the widget crashes..

I think that the problem is that it takes mid animation height as its new height at the time of toggle...

Please help...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.widget-minimize').click(function () {
            toggleMinimize($(this).parents('.widget').attr('id'));
        });

        $('.widget-close').click(function () {
            closeWidget($(this).parents('.widget').attr('id'));
        });
    });

    function toggleMinimize(widgetId) {
        var $content = $('#' + widgetId + ' .widget-content');
        if ($content.height()) {
            $content.data('oldheight', $content.height());
            $content.animate({height: 0});
            $('#' + widgetId).find('.widget-minimize').attr('src', 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/638285/SO/images/icon-maximize.png').attr('alt', 'maximize');
        }
        else {
            $content.animate({height: $content.data('oldheight')});
            $('#' + widgetId).find('.widget-minimize').attr('src', 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/638285/SO/images/icon-minimize.png').attr('alt', 'minimize');
        }
    }

    function closeWidget(widgetId) {
         $('#' + widgetId).animate({ "opacity": 0, "height": 0 }, 200, "swing");
    }
```

[Click here to see jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UcgSW/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return from your toggleMinimize function if your content is currently being animated, like this:

```
function toggleMinimize(widgetId) {
   var $content = $('#' + widgetId + ' .widget-content');
   if ($content.is(':animated')) {
       return;
   }
```

See [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UcgSW/8/)

Comment: +1. I was going to suggest using the option `complete` to set [a function to toggle a flag to achieve this](http://jsfiddle.net/UcgSW/7/), but yours is a much better and cleaner solution.

Comment: +1 Very good solution for this implementation - I'm leaving mine up only because I think it may help people in the future, but this is clearly the best solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery's `.stop()` method and its `:animated` selector. I often use them in situations like this to help me handle animations that are already running.

For example:

```
$("#element").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).not(":animated")) {
        ...animation code...
    }
});
```

and

```
$("#element").on("click", function() {
    $(this).stop();
    ...animation code...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the fiddle is working correctly, but I would recommend you to use `max-height` in case of height, so use `max-height: 0` and `max-height: 80` (assuming 80 is a bit more of the max height). Also you can pass the element and not just the ID.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.widget-minimize').click(function () {
        toggleMinimize($(this).parents('.widget'));
    });

    $('.widget-close').click(function () {
        closeWidget($(this).parents('.widget'));
    });
});

function toggleMinimize(selector) {
    var $content = $('.widget-content', selector);
    if ($content.height()) {
        $content.data('oldheight', $content.height());
        $content.animate({maxHeight: 0});
        $('.widget-minimize', selector).attr('src', 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/638285/SO/images/icon-maximize.png').attr('alt', 'maximize');
    }
    else {
        $content.animate({maxHeight: $content.data('oldheight')});
        $('.widget-minimize', selector).attr('src', 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/638285/SO/images/icon-minimize.png').attr('alt', 'minimize');
    }
}

function closeWidget(widgetId) {
     $('#' + widgetId).animate({ "opacity": 0, "max-height": 0 }, 200, "swing");
}
```